# Display Greek symbols and charge facet titles at the same time with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I know how to modify titles in ggplot without altering the original data. Suppose I have the following data frame and I want to change the labels. Then, I would do so in the following way

```
df <- data.frame(x = 1:4, y = 1:4, label = c(c("params[1]", "params[2]", "params[3]",
                                   "params[4]")))

params_names <- list(
  'params[1]'= "beta[11]",
  'params[2]'= "beta[22]",
  'params[3]'= "beta[33]",
  'params[4]'= "beta[44]"
)

param_labeller <- function(variable, value){
  params_names[value]
}

ggplot(df, aes(x=x,y=y)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(~label, labeller = param_labeller)
```

If I wanted to display the subscripts, I would just do this

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=x,y=y)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(~label, labeller = label_parsed)
```

How do I apply both operations at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly if this conflicts with you not wanting to "alter" the original data, but you add the labelling information to the factor itself:

```
df$label2 <- factor(df$label, 
                    labels = c("beta[4]", "beta[24]", "beta[42]", "beta[43]"))

ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid( ~ label2, labeller = label_parsed)
```

This produces the following plot:

[Plot with formatted facet labels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vEyzO.png)

Comment: Yes, it alters the original data.